# Ignore a Token output in Lucene's IncrementToken() method

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to make a custom filter in Lucene which simply recognizes whether two consequent words in a text start with a capital letter and have the rest as lower case, in which case the two words are to be joined as one token.

The overriden incrementToken method has the following code

```
@Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if(!input.incrementToken()){ 
     return false;}
     //Case were the previous token WAS NOT starting with capital letter and the     rest small   
     if(previousTokenCanditateMainName==false)
     {
            if(CheckIfMainName(termAtt.term()))
            {
                previousTokenCanditateMainName=true;
                tempString=this.termAtt.term() ;                           /*This is the*/
               // myToken.offsetAtt=this.offsetAtt;                             /*Token i need to "delete"*/
            tempStartOffset=this.offsetAtt.startOffset();
            tempEndOffset=this.offsetAtt.endOffset();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
 }
 //Case were the previous token WAS a Proper name (starting with Capital and continuiing with small letters)
     else
         {
         if(CheckIfMainName(termAtt.term()))
         {
             previousTokenCanditateMainName=false;
             posIncrAtt.setPositionIncrement(0);
             termAtt.setTermBuffer(tempString+TOKEN_SEPARATOR+this.termAtt.term());
             offsetAtt.setOffset(tempStartOffset, this.offsetAtt.endOffset());
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             previousTokenCanditateMainName=false;
             return true;
         }
     }

}
```

My question is how once i find the first Token that meets my requirements can i "ignore" it.
Currently the code works perfectly with joining the two tokens but i also get an extra token with the first one of the two that I identified.
I tried using the same method setEnableIncrementsPosition(true) as does the built-in stopFilter but in that case my filter needs to be a TokenFilter type which does not allow me to override the incrementToken method.

I hope i phrased my problem properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a custom method:

```
private void tokenize()
```

where you do the splitting and the custom joins. The resulting `List<String> tokens` need to be held as an attribute of the tokenizer.

In the `incrementToken` method you simply check if this `attribute` is `null` and initialize it if necessary.

You also need to add the tokens in the `incrementToken()` method to the `termAttribute`

```
termAttribute.append(tokens.get(tokenIndex));
```

this includes that your Tokenizer needs to have an attribute like this:

```
private CharTermAttribute termAttribute = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
```

Probably you need also some fine tuning. But thats only a draft on how this can be achieved in a pretty simple way.